# Prefix and suffix HTML to items in PHP array

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP array being created from a list of options in a WordPress plugin (`$checklist`) and I need to add some HTML to it.

```
public function get_the_checklist() {
  // The default list

  $options = get_option('uc_settings');
  if (isset($options['list'])) {
    $checklist = $options['list'];
    // Split the list by line break
    $checklist = preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', ($options['list']));
    // Convert to associative array
    foreach($checklist as $item) {
      $item = '<div>'.$item.'</div>';
      $default_checklist[] = array(
        'text' => $item
      );
    }
  }
  // Are we resetting to default?
  $reset = isset($_GET['reset_list']) ? true : false;
  if ($reset) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_checklist', $default_checklist);
    return $default_checklist;
  }
  // Is user logged in?
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Look for custom list
    $user_checklist = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_checklist', true);

    if (!$user_checklist) {
      $user_checklist = $default_checklist;
    }
  } else {
    return $default_checklist;
  }
  return $user_checklist;
}
```

I have done the following and it does add the prefix and suffix but it is showing as text and not HTML.

```
foreach($checklist as $item) {
  $item = '<div>'.$item.'</div>';
  $default_checklist[] = array(
    'text' => $item
  );
}
```

Here is an example of the output of the PHP above:

[image: example of output]

How can I make the text output as HTML instead?

Comment: Please add the code that prints out the array `$default_checklist`.

Comment: I added as much as I could find. I do not see any other reference to $default_checklist

Comment: There has to be some kind of output. All you do in the code you provided is save the div-strings in an array. There is no output involved.

Comment: Sorry, I have added more to the code, I am very inexperienced with PHP.

Comment: The code you posted is from the controller/model, it is just generating an array of items that will be printed in the view. You need to change the view function to add HTML to it. So you have to dig deeper: where is the function you posted called and where are the return data items sent to a view?

Comment: Probably somewhere `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is being run over the output, so that all the HTML special characters are HTML-encoded and will not be interpreted as HTML by your browser. The question is where this happens. Probably there's a good reason for it to happen there; maybe not. Find the source and find out :).